# vim flush saved password for NWrite?

Tags: vim

i use NWrite for deploing files via ftp protocol. once i use my NWrite command, vim asks me a password, and then it cache this password and doesn't ask me again until i close vim and reopen it. How can i flush this password without vim reload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NetUserPass()` function passing empty strings as arguments.

Check the documentation on [netrw-uidpass](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-uidpass), look at the third example. And you can read [netrw-login](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-login) also to know more about what netrw is doing.